# c# winform opacity 70% but panel inside opacity 100%

Tags: c#, winforms, opacity

I have windows Form with opacity 70% that Im using as an overlay when getting data from server.

Inside my Form I have a panel that is centered containing "Please Wait..." text. Right now this panel is also affected with opacity but I want to override that for the panel so the panel opacity is 100%.

Any clue?

Thanks a lot

Comment: See: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/43124fb0-3422-42a8-93d4-e76c4410ac42/semitransparent-form-with-no-transparent-control

Comment: This isn't supported until Windows 8.  Given its popularity, you'll have to wait another decade before you can rely on it.  The simple workaround is to display another form on top.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can make a contained panel more opaque than its container, so it won't be as simple as just setting the opacity.

Two ideas occur to me:

1. Make your "Please Wait..." not be a child of your Form.  If it's a top-level form in its own right, you can set whatever opacity you want on it, and not worry about its parents.
2. Make your top-level form have an opacity of 100%, and change all of its children to have an opacity of 70%, other than the "Please Wait..." panel.

Of the two, the first sounds less ugly - it just means you need an extra top-level form.  The second one isn't really that bad, though, you just have to iterate through all the children of the top form.

Comment: Following your advice I create a frmOverlay that is a 70% opacity form. Then from my main form I show it. Then inside frmOverlay.Load event I create an instance of frmPleaseWait form that is a 100% opacity and I do also a frm.Show(this). Seems its working fine. Both forms are not Top-Most so I dont want to see the "Please wait" if the application is in the background. What do you think?

Comment: @VAAA If you mean `frmPleaseWait.Show(this)`, get rid of the `(this)`.  Otherwise, you're making the `frmOverlay` be the other one's parent.